# Open a file with Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

Dears,

I 'm facing some difficulties trying to create a batch script to open a specific excel file with variable name.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') 
do set %%x
set today=%Year%%Month%%Day%
"C:\xxx\xxx\Desktop\FileName" + today-1 + ".xlsx"
```

The path includes two pieces:
Fix piece :"C:\xxx\xxx\Desktop\FileName"
Variable piece: yesterday's date in format "YYYYMMDD" without any separation between year,month or day.

thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot do date math like that in batch files.  Batch file know nothing of any other variable type.  Everything is a string.  You don't use + symbols either to concatenate things together.  If you want the date minus one then call out to Powershell inside your `FOR` command instead of `WMIC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use powershell as a tool to do the date calculation:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\11\SO_52760062.cmd
@ECHO OFF
for /f "usebackq" %%A in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')"
`) Do Set Yesterday=%%A
echo "C:\xxx\xxx\Desktop\FileName%Yesterday%.xlsx"
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\10\11\SO_52760062.cmd
"C:\xxx\xxx\Desktop\FileName20181010.xlsx"
```